# Where should I save the .exe file in Windows HPC Cluster?

Tags: azure, hpc

I am working on HPC Pack cluster. I want to use the HPC Pack Job Manager to run my tasks.

Where should I save the .exe file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If the application is installed on a file share, specify the UNC path to the >executable file. For example, type \server_name\Program Files\myapp.exe.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919677(v=ws.11).aspx